# Why can we assume $\pi = 0.5$ in sign test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, sign-test

When using the sign test, we assume, that:

$\textrm{test statistic} \sim Bi(n_+ + n_-, 0.5)$

ie. that the probablity of $+$ or $-$ to occur is $0.5$. But how about the case of values being the same (resulting in $0$). The probablity of $0$s increases when dealing with ordinal variables.

How can the probablity still be $0.5$? What am I missing on?

Comment: You're overlooking the important assumption that the underlying distributions are *continuous*: see the first line in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test), for instance. You shouldn't be applying the sign test to ordinal data.

Comment: @whuber: the same article says "The values Xi and Yi represent are ordered (at least the ordinal scale), so the comparisons "greater than", "less than", and "equal to" are meaningful.". Confused... Also my textbook says that it can be applied to ordinal variables. I understand, that for cardinal data, the probablity $\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: "Ordinal" simply means "ordered": it does not invariably mean the data are discrete! The continuity assumption says otherwise. And yes, of course "equal to" is meaningful: but the import of the continuity assumption is that the chance of obtaining two equal values will always be zero, no matter how much data you have. Therefore, if your data have an appreciable number of ties, the sign test is not applicable to them. (A few ties can be tolerated; people have developed adjustments in the test statistic to handle them.)

Comment: @whuber: Alright, thanks. Post it as an answer please.

Comment: Because of the continuity, you can basically only do the sign test if you condition on the unequal pairs.